# pathlib.Patch.cwd() isn't working in TeamCity

Tags: python, pytest, teamcity

I am using `pytest` and `pathlib.Path` in my test

It's working fine on my PC. But in TeamCity Linux build I have an error:

> File not found error: No such file or directory  '$SRC_DIR/tables/table_name.json'

My code:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def make_action():
    return my_foo("table_name", dir_path=Path.cwd() / "tables")    

def my_foo(table_name: str, tmp_path):
    with open(tmp_path / f"{table_name}.json", "r") as f: # error in this line
        ...
```

The problem is -- team city identifies `Path.cwd()` as `'$SRC_DIR/tables'` but I want real path

Found out that `SRC_DIR` is an anaconda env variable https://conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/user-guide/environment-variables.html

Comment: What is SRC_DIR defined as and where? Do you get "$SRC_DIR" literally, or the expansion of it?

Comment: I was looking for "SRC_DIR" in my code and in TeamCity configuration, but didn't find

Comment: @DannyStaple found out that  `SRC_DIR` is an env variable in anaconda  https://conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/user-guide/environment-variables.html

Comment: Is the anaconda environment installed and activated in the team city environment this runs in?